# How to build native apps for Gentoo 64bit (Linux kernel 2.6) using Qt SDK?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, fastcgi, gentoo

unfortunately I am new to Linux. I have made a virtual machine with Linux Mint 13 (32bit), installed Qt 5.0 with Qt Creator. I was given a task to create a simple FastCGI app for the server running Gentoo 64bit. This app must use Qt stuff.
The installation of 64bit Qt 5.0 through SSH failed due to the libSM.so.6 (shared object) absense.
How can I make this stuff work? Should I create another VM with Gentoo 64bit in order to train with Qt installation and not to mix 32bit and 64bit? My simple FastCGI app will work as a backend for a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop everywhere you want. When you want to deploy, simply build the project on the Gentoo machine.

Note that you don't need to install Qt 5 manually on Gentoo. It is offered in the "qt" overlay.  You add it with layman:

```
layman -a qt
```

Then you can emerge the Qt components you need by using slot 5. For example, to get Qt Core:

```
emerge -a qt-core:5
```

If you have never used Layman before, it's in the "app-portage/layman" package and you can find docs here:

http://layman.sourceforge.net